# How to add docker-dind to an image with a base

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-in-docker

For CI purposes I need an agent docker image that supports Java, Maven and Docker. I need docker in the agent to be able to run my tests against databases that we setup in containers.

I added docker to the image installing it like this:

```
# Needed for yum-config-manager
RUN microdnf -y update \
    && microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y yum-utils \
    && microdnf clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

# Install Docker
RUN yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo \
    && microdnf -y update \
    && microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y docker-ce \
    && microdnf clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

This allowed me to execute the docker commands. However, this setup passes all the docker commands to the docker daemon outside/above the agent container. An image like this is called DooD (Docker outside of Docker). I could still work with this, however it brings all kind of problems regarding cleanup: I am required to clean the images and containers myself, as will all other users of the image. Furthermore, the communication between my test running inside the agent container and my database containers is difficult to setup as they all need to be in the same docker network.

My question is: How do I add docker as DinD (Docker in Docker) to the agent image? All I find on the internet is to use the `docker:x.y.z-dind` image as a base. Unfortunately, that is not an option as I am required to use a certain base image by the organisation I work for. Are there other options?

--- Update in response to [kamilcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) ---

Thank you. I will not deny the possibility that I may do something that causes the behaviour. However, in that case I am not aware of it. What could it be that I do that passes the commands up? So I'll post the commands I execute:

```
DOCKER_BUILD_IMAGE_COMMAND is: docker build --build-arg DB_NAME=my_db . -t rp/my_db --progress=plain

DOCKER_RUN_COMMAND is docker run -d -p 3258:3250 --name my_db rp/my_db:latest
```

I have added the commands you suggested to the start of my docker setup script. However, the result is the same. My dockers are still created outside

Comment: That setup where you're trying to embed multiple language runtimes and also a dedicated Docker daemon sounds almost like a virtual machine; can your CI system run that?  Or can your CI system itself clean up after its own containers, or manage a separate DinD container (if you truly must)?

Comment: On gitlab it was no problem to use the docker:dind image this way. Why would it be a problem? For integration tests and functional tests where you setup the dependent systems (resources like databases) this is very useful.

However, this discussion is beside the point. The problem I am facing is that I cannot derive from docker:dind otherwise I would. The question thus is: How to add docker dind to an existing image?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add docker as DinD (Docker in Docker) to the agent image?

It's already added, you have to execute `dockerd` deamon process when your container starts.

```
# entrypoint.sh
dockerd &
# wait for docker to initialize
while ! docker info; do sleep 1; done 

your_other_commands_amazing_commands
```

> However, this setup passes all the docker commands

I would disagree - there is nothing *in showed parts of the Dockerfile* that would setup that. When you *run* the container, most probably you configure that. So don't.

Comment: Thank you. I will not deny the possibility that I may do something that causes the behaviour. However, in that case I am not aware of it. So I'll post the commands I execute:

Comment: Updated the question with the commands that create the image and run the container.